# C# : sql update command no longer works

Tags: c#, sql

this is sample :

there is no error and it worked perfectly before.

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
public bool updateData()
    {
        try
        {
            connection.Open();

            string sqlQuery = "UPDATE Other SET count = '1'";

            cmd.CommandText = sqlQuery;

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            cmd.Clone();

            return true;
        }
        catch
        {
            //
        }
        finally
        {
            connection.Close();
        }

        return false;
    }
```

Comment: No error perhaps because you didn't put any exception handling code in the `catch` block?

Comment: **Never write an empty `catch` block**! Ever. You will never know if and why something failed. Also what this the result of `ExecuteNonQuery`, you never check and it returns the number of affected records. Those are your 2 best guesses and I do mean guess because there is no way for anyone to know with the limited information you provided. If you want more help please create an [mcve].

Comment: it doesn't enter in catch block !

Comment: Use Sql Profiler and check if query is actually executing or not. Also check the connection string when you open connection.

Comment: Guessing here: is `count` a number? If so, your query should probably be `UPDATE Other SET count = 1` without the quotes around the `1`

Comment: ExecuteNonQuery return 1 but no thing is changed

Comment: How do you know exactly that it does not work? I'm betting it does work, you're just falsely concluding that it doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution :**

I have 2 connection strings, one is the location of database in my pc and the other is to use in client pc.

I have been used the wrong connection string, so when i used the connection string that refers to the location of database on my pc .. it works !

thanks everyone,

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public bool updateData(){
            _conn.ConnectionString = conn;
            string comando = "";
            try{
                _conn.Open();
                comando = "UPDATE Other SET count = 1";
                //YOUR DB CLIENT COMES HERE
                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(comando, _conn);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                _conn.Close();
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex){
                ex.Message.ToString();
                _conn.Close();
            }
            return false;

}
```